# Bootstrap 4, styles for forms missing

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

Im using the newest version of Bootstrap4 (in combination with angular5).

When I copy inline-checkboxes from the documentation page the box is misaligned.
When I copy custom-checkboxes the box is missing.

I included ngBootstrap and also the bootstrap.min.css.

I didn't add any custom styles yet.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Could you copy some code of yours?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven´t done this then do it now.

Add link to bootstrap.min.css in your style.css

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

and also in your .angular-cli.json

```
 "prefix": "app",
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
     "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
],
```

Check if Bootstrap works in your HTML file

```
<div class="jumbotron"></div>
```

Comment: most of bootstrap works, there is just a few things missing.